# Failed to load user control at design time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am having problems with a user control. I cannot placed it on a form.

To make a test, I have created now a new UserControl. I have added just a button on it. Then, I have created a new Form. Then compiled.

After that, I loaded the form design view. I can see in toolbox the "UserControl1" I have created. Then, I drag that user control from the toolbox and drop into the form and the following error occurs:

[image: Error]

After I cick OK button, the user control is removed from the toolbox.

What may be happening here?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and building against .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: Did you try a clean & rebuild of the solution?  This usually fixes it for me.

Comment: A restart of visual studio is also sometimes needed for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was that I was building for x64 platform and my VS2012 is x86. At development time, I will use x86 and use x64 only for deployment.